# MySQL - How to make a DATEDIFF in years?

Tags: mysql, trigger, date

This is my first post (and English is not my mother tongue) so I hope I won't screw this post up.

I am new to MySQL but I learned a lot with 100+ youtube tutorials and your numerous posts. I designed my database using PHPmyadmin and MySQL Workbench.

In my table `subventions` (grants), I created a trigger to be able to calculate the annual amount of money of a grant, using my columns `subventions.début` (beginning), `subventions.fin` (end) and `subventions.montant` (amount).

As `DATEDIFF` only gives me an answer in days, I naively thought that I only had to divide it by 365 days to obtain my answer. It works if my beginning date is the first of january and the end date the 31st of December, but does not if it stars somewhere else during the year. Here is my trigger:

```
SET NEW.montant_annuel = NEW.montant / (datediff(NEW.fin,NEW.début)/365)
```

Here is my table and the result in the 'montant_annuel' column:
[image: Tableau : Subventions]

If I use 365.25 (which is the "real" number of days in a year), it does not work either.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Comme a dit l'autre (@Erik) - t'inquiète pour ton anglais (don't worry about your English). Have you looked at the [YEAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function?

Comment: @Vérace: how would I apply that function..?

Comment: @Erik My bad for Grant2 end date... should be 2014-05-31!

Comment: Try `SET NEW.montant_annuel = year(fin)-year(debut)+1`

Comment: Try:  `TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAYS,NEW.début,NEW.fin);` for days and `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,NEW.début,NEW.fin);` for years.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, TIMESTAMPDIFF is the best approach:

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,'2011-01-01', now() ) ;  --> 4
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,'2011-08-28', now() ) ;  --> 4 
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,'2011-09-01', now() ) ;  --> 3
```

Comment: Great! The only problem with that is that it considers 2012-01-01 to 2012-12-31 as 0 year... it will only consider 2012-01-01 to 2013-01-01 as one year...

Comment: Solved it, just add +1 as @Jehad suggested it.

`SET NEW.montant_annuel_UL = NEW.montant / (TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,NEW.début,NEW.fin)+1)`

I just hope my grants dates will always be from the 1st of the month to the last day of another month...

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on these boards, but really credit should go to @Vérace.

Look at the [TimeStampDiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), it looks like it should subtract/add your dates and can output the result in months.  Note that without the timepart, it will use 00:00:00 as the timepart.

EDIT:

```
SET NEW.montant_annuel = NEW.montant * (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, NEW.début, DATE_ADD(NEW.fin,INTERVAL 86399 SECOND)))
```

I don't have a MySQL installation to test, but should be similar in function to SQL Server with different syntax.

Comment: You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to test your answer.